# forward_call with local variables

Tags: coq, verifiable-c

VST version 1.7.

I'm having an issue where coq won't recognize locally declared variables when I try to use them in a function call. I have the code:

```
void deSignArray(int bits[], int invKey, int size)
{
int i = 0;
while (i < size) {
int bit = bits[i];
int ans = deSignInt(bit, invKey);
bits[i] = ans;
i++;
}
}
```

with coq types bits : list Z, invKey : Z, size : Z.

I successfully stepped through the bit = bits[i] step, but when I then try to step forwards using

```
forward_call((Int.repr bit), (Int.repr invKey)).
```

the step fails with bit not being found in the environment. I tried using

```
forward_call(_bit, (Int.repr invKey)).
```

as _bit appears in the LOCAL clause, but that provides a typing mismatch since _bit is an ident type and not an int or Z type. I'm wondering how I am supposed to use my locally defined values to call other functions as a result, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The argument that you provide to forward_call, in your case (Int.repr bit, Int.repr invKey), must be a Coq value.  In your case, if (at the time of forward_call) you have *above the line* in your Coq proof goal, variables "bit" and "invKey", then this should work.

How would you get such variables above the line?  If the LOCALS part of your function precondition contains (temp _invKey (Vint (Int.repr invkey))), then you should have invKey above the line.  And then, after going **forward** through the load statement (bit = bits[i]), your current proof goal's precondition should have a LOCALS of the form (temp _bit something-or-other), and it's that something-or-other that you should use instead of "bit".

Comment: Thanks. That did clear up the problem there, though it does feel very strange to use the specific value in the proof script rather than a reference. Good to know for the rest of the proof (particularly in main).